# How to format phone number using XSLT v1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I wanted to change phone format from (###) ###-#### to ##########.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the characters you don't want via [**`translate()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate):

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($phonenum, '()- ', '')" />
```

---

**Complete XSLT example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="phonenum">(123) 456-7890</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($phonenum, '()- ', '')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will return**

```
1234567890
```

**as requested.**

Comment: Thank you. As you said, translate() is working fine.

Comment: @Abdulkadir: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.